# Circle with two points and arrows on it

Tags: tikz-pgf

would like to have a picture of a circle with two nodes at positions +60° and -60°. The point at +60° represents a stable equilibrium and the other an unstable one. So I would like to have an arrow at 0° point to the upper equilibrium (this is already in the picture below) and an arrow at, say 185° point in the direction of the equilibrium at -60°.

Moreover, I would like to have the arrows a bit larger and to write some names for the equilibria beside them.

Unfortunately I do not know how to realize the second arrow, a larger size of the two arrows and the names besides the nodes.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]

     % draw circle and arrows on it
    \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.0 with {\arrow[very thick]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate}] (0cm,0cm) circle(0.5cm);

  % draw the two points 
  \foreach \x in {60,-60} {

    \filldraw[black] (\x:0.5cm) circle(0.5pt);
            % draw each angle in degrees
            }\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following example draws the arrow heads as end points of real arrows.
Library `bending` and option `bend` try to make nicer arrow heads.

The annotations can be specified by nodes, see the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
  \def\Radius{.5cm}

  \draw (0cm,0cm) circle[radius=\Radius];

  \begin{scope}[
    -{Stealth[round, length=8pt, width=8pt, bend]},
    shorten >=4pt,
    very thin,
  ]
    \draw (\Radius, 0) arc(-3:3:\Radius);
    \draw (-\Radius, 0) arc(180+3:180-3:\Radius);
  \end{scope}

  % draw the two points 
  \fill[radius=.7pt]
    (60:\Radius) circle[] node[above right] {stable equilibrium}
    (-60:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {unstable equilibrium}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Text along side the circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
  \def\Radius{.5cm}

  \draw (0cm,0cm) circle[radius=\Radius];

  \begin{scope}[
    -{Stealth[round, length=8pt, width=8pt, bend]},
    shorten >=4pt,
    very thin,
  ]
    \draw (\Radius, 0) arc(-3:3:\Radius);
    \draw (-\Radius, 0) arc(180+3:180-3:\Radius);
  \end{scope}

  % draw the two points 
  \fill[radius=.7pt]
    (60:\Radius) circle[] node[above right] {stable equilibrium}
    (-60:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {unstable equilibrium}
  ;

  \def\Item#1#2(#3:#4){%
    \path[
      decoration={
        text along path,
        text={Section #1},
        text align=center,
      },
      decorate,
    ]
      (#3:\Radius-#2) arc(#3:#4:\Radius-#2)
    ;
  }
  \Item A 1pt (-60:0)
  \Item B 1pt (180:300)
  \Item C 2pt (180:60)
  \Item D 2pt (60:0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Simple letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
  \def\Radius{.5cm}

  \draw (0cm,0cm) circle[radius=\Radius];

  \begin{scope}[
    -{Stealth[round, length=8pt, width=8pt, bend]},
    shorten >=4pt,
    very thin,
  ]
    \draw (\Radius, 0) arc(-3:3:\Radius);
    \draw (-\Radius, 0) arc(180+3:180-3:\Radius);
  \end{scope}

  % draw the two points 
  \fill[radius=.7pt]
    (60:\Radius) circle[] node[above right] {stable equilibrium}
    (-60:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {unstable equilibrium}
  ;
  \path
    (-30:\Radius) node[above left] {A}
    (240:\Radius) node[above right] {B}
    (120:\Radius) node[below right] {C}
    (30:\Radius) node[below left] {D}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Sorry, the second arrow should point to the stable equilibrium, too. What do I have to change?

Comment: @mathfemi The direction of the second arrow needs changing. Answer fixed.

Comment: May I ask another question? How can I label the section between the unstable equilibrium and the arrow to its left such that it is bend around the circle segment? F.e. call the segements A, B, C and D clockwise?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
\documentclass[border=0.4in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5, >=latex, radius = 1]
  \draw[thick, arrows = {-Latex[length=10]}]
    (2:1) arc[start angle = 2, end angle = 210];
  \draw[thick, arrows = {-Latex[length=10]}]
    (212:1) arc[start angle = 212, end angle = 360];
  \fill (60:1) circle[radius=0.02] node[above right] (n1) {my first node};
  \fill (-60:1) circle[radius=0.02] node[below right] (n2) {my second node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]