# Arrows on edge of circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a circle with 8 nodes and different arrows on each of the edges, as below:

[image]

So far I have made the circle with the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0, 0) circle (2);
     \foreach \x in {1,...,8} {
          \node[shape=circle,fill=black, scale=0.5] at ({((\x-1)*360/8)+90}:2) {};
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I have seen [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409894/arrows-on-circle) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466514/arrows-on-edges-of-polygon) which are similar, but seem quite complicated and I'm wondering if there's an easier way about this.

Comment: may be this post can help You https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329231/circle-with-two-points-and-arrows-on-it

Answer (score 2):

Your hand-drawing is unclear on the arrow in the middle of the arc from `-135` to `-180`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\tikzset{myarrow/.style args={at position #1 with #2}{
postaction={decorate},
decoration={markings,          % switch on markings
mark=at position #1 with {#2}
}}}
    
\draw (0,0) circle(2);
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}
\fill[magenta] (45*\i:2) circle(2pt);

\path[
myarrow=at position .5 with {\arrow{latex}}] 
(0:2) arc(0:-45:2);

\path[
myarrow=at position .45 with {\arrow{latex}},
myarrow=at position .55 with {\arrow{latex}}] 
(-45:2) arc(-45:-90:2);

\path[
myarrow=at position .58 with {\arrow{latex}},
myarrow=at position .5 with {\arrow{latex}},
myarrow=at position .42 with {\arrow{latex}}] 
(-90:2) arc(-90:-135:2);

\path[
myarrow=at position .35 with {\arrow{latex}},
myarrow=at position .45 with {\arrow{latex}},
myarrow=at position .55 with {\arrow{latex}},
myarrow=at position .65 with {\arrow{latex}}] (-135:2) arc(-135:-180:2);


\path[
myarrow=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}] 
(180:2) arc(180:135:2);

\path[
myarrow=at position .47 with {\arrow{>}},
myarrow=at position .53 with {\arrow{>}}] (135:2) arc(135:90:2);

\path[
myarrow=at position .45 with {\arrow{>}},
myarrow=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}},
myarrow=at position .55 with {\arrow{>}}] (90:2) arc(90:45:2);

\path[
myarrow=at position .425 with {\arrow{>}},
myarrow=at position .475 with {\arrow{>}},
myarrow=at position .525 with {\arrow{>}},
myarrow=at position .575 with {\arrow{>}}] (45:2) arc(45:0:2);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```